# Уникальность записываемых данных в БД MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Я сделал парсер, который каждые 30 минут берет объявления с форума о недвижимости и записывает их в базу данных MySQL. Но сейчас в БД много записей-дубликатов. Далее я сделал в таблице, куда сохраняются объявления поле uniq. Туда записывается уникальное значение, пример - showthread.php?s=4ad705f976ce73fb739b76820a3a573f&amp;t=1485914 (последние 7 цифер у каждого объявления уникальны!). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне лучше, теперь, организовать проверку объявления на уникальность? Заранее спасибо, за любую помощь.

Comment: Мне нужно при записи новых объявлений проверять нет ли их УЖЕ в базе данных, чтоб не создавать множество дубликатов.

Comment: update? перезапишет дубликат

Comment: @Gorets не совсем понял зачем использовать update? Можете пояснить, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, читать учебники на тему UNIQUE KEY и INSERT IGNORE...

Answer (score 2):

Пошаманьте в сторону ON DUPLICATE KEY.

Answer (score 0):

А что мешает просто записывать ид объявления из строки адреса?

```
showthread.php?s=4ad705f976ce73fb739b76820a3a573f&amp;t=1485914
```

тут же - t= это и есть скорее всего ид объявления, который уникален. По нему и проверять.

Comment: И вместо одного insert делать 2 запроса: select + insert. Конечно, какая-то оптимизация тут нужна хотя бы для того, чтобы не вытягивать лишнее, но это уже в другом месте :)

Comment: На самом деле не особо. Если поле у тебя с индексом, то там запрос типа выбрать записить с таким-то числовым id делается настолько быстро, что можно принебречь этим.

Comment: Зависит от. Мы не знаем всех масштабов трагедии :) Вот навскидку:  можно сначала получить список всех t, исключить те, что есть в базе, а по остальным уже выкачивать и добавлять. Само собой, исключить - одними селектом, а не на каждый t.

Comment: Не очень понял тебя. "получить список всех t" - откуда получить? Если надо проверить наличие в бд набора значений чего-то есть в sql опратов IN, ну типа во: select * from notes where id IN(23,43,54,55,123,344). Вообще советую получше изучить синтаксис sql + особенности той субд, с которой работаешь, тогда многое сразу станет понятнее и легче.

Comment: Понятия не имею, откуда. Но предполагаю, что сначала парсятся страницы форума со сылками на объявления, вот оттуда и берутся строки вида "showthread.php?s=4ad705f976ce73fb739b76820a3a573f&amp;t=148591". А с советами - это не ко мне :)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего организвать эту проверку силами СУБД. Объявить первичный ключ (поле или набор полей, которые полностью определеют запись и не могут быть равны NULL) или ограничение на уникальность (значения поля, не равные NULL повторяться не могут, а равные - могут :)). Но сначала надо удалить дубликаты.

Добавить ограничение можно так : 
ALTER TABLE myTable
ADD CONSTRAINT constraintName 
UNIQUE (mycolumn)
;